# How to use substitution on register?

Tags: substitute, register, ex-mode

Let say I've register which has string stored in it, but I'd like to use *substitute* command to change it.

For example I've 5x5 html table:

```
let @t='<table>'.repeat('<tr>'.repeat('<td>_</td>',5).'</tr>',5).'</table>'
```

and I'd like to replace placeholder (`_`) with some other data ideally by modifying existing register (not assigning to another).

I've tried the following syntax:

```
"ts/_/test/g
"@ts/_/test/g " with modifiable set
```

which doesn't give any errors, but it doesn't work as expected (in similar way as prefixing with `%` works).

What's the proper way of doing that?

Comment: You look like you want something like [Emmet](http://emmet.io/).

Comment: Note that [`:help function-list`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_41.txt.html#function-list) is a very useful page ;-) There are also some other tags in that page, such as `string-functions`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ex commands work on the buffer contents; for register (or variable) contents, you need to use a corresponding Vimscript function (if it exists).

For `:substitute`, the equivalent is `substitute()` (that was easy, right?) So:

```
:let @t = substitute(@t, '_', 'test', 'g')
```

Comment: `substitute()` isn't *completely* equivalent to `:substitute`; the function behaves as if `'magic'` is set and `'cpoptions'` is empty, whereas the command will observe user-set values.

Answer (score 5):

Apart from using the let-statement and dealing with vim-script, you need to paste it into a buffer and then yank it back to the register:

1. <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>
2. <kbd>:</kbd>`.s/_/test/g`
3. <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>